# Magento 2 CMS Page 'Layout Update XML' option add xml code to get custom meta tag

Tags: xml, magento2, magento2.1

I know how to add custom meta tag in a **Magento 1** CMS page using 'Layout Update XML' option.

```
<reference name="head">
    <block type="core/text" name="custommeta">
        <action method="setText">
            <text>
                <![CDATA[<meta data-customid="customid_meta_1" />]]>
            </text>
        </action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

How I can add meta tag in the same way for a specific CMS page in **Magento 2** using option 'Layout Update XML'

```
<meta data-customid="customid_meta_1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think following should work for you

```
<head>
    <meta name="data-customid" content="customid_meta_1"/>
</head>
```

you may see *vendor\magento\module-theme\view\frontend\layout\default_head_blocks.xml* file for reference.

Magento1 code for the same meta can be found in the following file *app\design\frontend\rwd\default\layout\page.xml*

```
<!-- Sets viewport meta tag using text block -->
<block type="core/text" name="head.viewport">
      <action method="setText"><text><![CDATA[<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />]]>&#10;</text></action>
</block>
```

Also check following file *vendor\magento\framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer.php* for the **getMetadataTemplate** method

**Update:**  check [CMS Page with  in layout update xml](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4454)

Comment: Thanks @muk but I don't want to add normal meta tag with 'name' and 'content'. I need this meta tag to be added - <meta data-customid="customid_meta_1" />